# left to right evaluation of statements inside of a for loop separated by comma

Tags: c, for-loop, comma-operator

Are these both codes same? These statements inside of for loop are written in same line separated by comma. Will they be evaluated for left to right?

Also i wanted to ask can i use as many as statements inside of for loop separated by comma. Like for(i=0, j=0, k=0; .......) ?

```
for(i=0, j= strlen(s)-1; i<j; i++, j--){ 
     c=s[i];
     s[i]=s[j];
     s[j]=c;
}
```

and

```
for(i=0, j= strlen(s)-1; i<j; i++, j--)
      c=s[i],s[i]=s[j],s[j]=c;
```

Comment: The latter string of comma-separated assignments buys you nothing but obfuscation. The usage in the for-loop definition (not the body) is appropriate. And I'll warn you, if `i` and `j` are *unsigned* types (such as `size_t` or `unsigned int`) *and* you pass a zero-length string `s` into this (0-terminator at `s[0]`, you're not going to like the results.

Comment: @Lord Zsolt hehehe no i'll not use if you say

Comment: @LZ: I like the comma operator.  I think sometimes it can make a function easier to read.  If the important concepts in a function are not the individual assignments to multiple variables, this compacts what is unimportant.  I vote that it's a valid language construct that c programmers should understand. What's next? Killing because of indentation and line feeds before curly brackets?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The C comma operator evaluates each of the two operands, discarding the result of the first and returning the second. With more than one comma, the operator is left associative so the effect is an evaluation from left to right.

Your second example will thus do the same thing as your first example. However it is poor style because there is no *reason* to use the comma operator, unlike `i=0, j-strlen(s)-1` within the body of the `for` statement, where a semicolon could not have been used.

Answer (score 3):

`,` operator is evaluated left to right and there is a sequence point between the evaluation of the left and the right operand, so it means both codes are equivalent.